# Error when using fetch_object (can't loop through items in db to output in a table)

Tags: php, html, database, mysqli

I am having an issue with getting a confirmation message show after I add users to my database.

Currently I can add users by filling out some texts fields, when submitted the data from the fields gets sent to my database, after the users get added they are supposed to get a confirmation message, after that there is a while loop that loops through the items in my db and outputs the data in a html table.

Instead though I get this error message: `Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_object() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\index.php on line 51`.

```
<?php
//create connection using oop
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'bachi619', 'company');

//check connection
if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
    printf("Connection failed %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Select all from employees we use the query method
$result=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM employees")

?>

<h1>Employees</h1>
<table width="500" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
<tr>
    <th>ID#</th>
    <th>First</th>
    <th>Last</th>
    <th>Dept</th>
    <th>Email</th>
</tr>
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_object()): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row->id; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $row->first_name?></th>
        <th><?php echo $row->last_name?></th>
        <th><?php echo $row->department?></th>
        <th><?php echo $row->email?></th>
    </tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>

</table>

<?php
//Get products
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT products.name, categories.name AS 'category', products.id AS 'prodid'
    FROM products
    LEFT JOIN categories ON products.category = categoties.id");
?>

<h1>Products</h1>
<table width="500" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5" border="1">
<tr>
    <th>ID#</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Category</th>
</tr>
<?php while($row = $result->fetch_object()): ?>
    <tr>
        <th><?php echo $row->prodid; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $row->name; ?></th>
        <th><?php echo $row->category; ?></th>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Why am I getting an error when using `fetch_object`?

Comment: What does `mysqli_error()` return?

Comment: You have a typo: `categoties.id` should be `categories.id`. Now do you see why you should check for errors?

Comment: Barmar thank you very much, I was going crazy with that. Simple mistake that I simply did not see. Thank you very much.

Comment: You apparently made little attempt to debug this. You don't display errors in your code, you didn't try running the query by hand (always copy/paste, don't retype).

Comment: You should test $result for not FALSE values.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems.

Firstly, you are not testing the value of result, so you assume your query works, when in fact it does not.

Secondly, your query does not work because you spelt the table name wrong ('categoties' instead of 'categories').

```
$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT products.name, categories.name AS 'category', products.id AS 'prodid'
    FROM products
    LEFT JOIN categories ON products.category = categories.id");
if (!result) {
   show_some_error();
}
```